# Obstacles work in Unity Editor but not in the build

Tags: unity, path-finding

As the title states my code works in editor view but not when I Build it.

I need to dynamically place and remove Obstacles in a NavMesh.

Can anyone give some insight why this happens?

Comment: to clarify: im using unity4

Comment: This is going to need a lot more detail before anyone can offer more than a link to the docs. What are you trying to do? What game objects & scripts are you using to do it? In what way does it not work? What are the symptoms?

Answer (score 1):

try and have a look at this: http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-NavMeshObstacle.html
you could make a prefab of the Obstacle you want to place, load it with (GameObject)Resources.Load("Obstacle") and then spawn it where you want.

To give you a more in-depth answer you should be able to post the section of your code that handles obstacles, until that, this is the solution I would use for that problem.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems Unity4 had a general problem with placing obstacles in a Navmesh. I have swapped to Unity5 which works as intended.

Comment: I've used NavMeshObstacles in Unity 4.6 without any difficulty, so it may be something more specific than the engine version that was causing your problem (whatever that problem was)